# Testing comorbidity adjusting for patient characteristics

Tags: ancova

I have data of patients of a large hospital with columns representing different mental and physical illnesses and patients constituting the rows. The data are in binary form (1 = patient has disease; 0 = patient does not have the disease).

I want to test, given a certain mental disease, whether there are significant differences between the occurance of the physical diseases adjusted for demographic characteristics. That is, are certain physical diseases "overrepresented" in e.g. depressive patients controlling for age and gender?

My supervisor wanted to calculate some kind of analysis of covariance with the mental ilnesses as the grouping factor, which seems inappropriate given the nature of the data. Which alternative tests could I use to answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the true goal of the study, it seems that what your supervisor suggested is closer to what's probably needed.  The way you phrased the question suggests an indirect analysis.  We are usually interested in knowing whether comorbidities predict the probability of a specific disease (here, a mental disorder that is strangely assumed to be all-or-nothing) after accounting for how other variables are associated with the mental disease.  One issue that frequently arises is that there are too many comorbidities to model all of them as separate variables, and you may want to include the more frequent ones or summarize them using a publish comorbidity index such as Elixhauser's.

Comment: Do you think the Elixhauser's is better than the Charlson Comorbidity Index?  Trying to decide which one to use as a covariate in a study about healthcare utilization of epilepsy patients.

Comment: Elixhauser's is way, way better than Charlson's but there are more comprehensive comorbidity indexes about there.  You might start this as a discussion on datamethods.org where health services researchers and epidemiologists take part.

Comment: Did not know about that site, thanks so much for the reference.